# angularjs form can not refer to input control when input name is array

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I encounter a problem when testing form validation with angularjs

According to [angularjs form guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms),

> an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control.

I created test code at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m2pC2UNjTOpb3LbMcw0g?p=info), it all works fine untill I change the input name from

```
<input type="number" name="age" ng-model="user.age" max="100" required>

<p>{{form1.age.$error}}</p>
```

to

```
<input type="number" name="user[age]" ng-model="user.age" max="100" required>

<p>{{form1.user[age].$error}}</p>
```

#### Does this mean angular can not recognize array syntax in form input?

The problem for me is I want to keep the normal form submission flow and only use angular for form validation, so I need to keep form input as array to work with the backend form handling

Comment: What are you trying to gain by setting a dynamic name on an element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Angular. It is a syntactic JS error.

If you want to reference a property named `user[age]`, you should do it like this:

```
form1['user[age]'].$error
```

<sub>`form1.user[age]` is incorrectly interpreted as `(form1.user)[age]`</sub>