# pass an input name with an array to ng-show

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to pass an input name to ng-show.
When the input's name is not an array, this works just fine (if it's just 'entity' instead of 'entity[entity_name]'), but when there's an array it's not working.
something about this syntax - 'ng-show = "investForm.entity[entity_name].$error.pattern"' is wrong:

```
<form name="investForm">
    <label>Entity Name</label>
    <input name="entity[entity_name]" rc-forms ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+$/" type="text" ng-model="invest.entity_name" ng-required="invest.is_entity" />
        <div ng-show="investForm.entity[entity_name].$dirty && investForm.entity[entity_name].$invalid">
            <span ng-show="investForm.entity[entity_name].$error.pattern">Error: Please use English characters only!</span>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ containing the necessary javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question pretty intriguing, so I've been Googling for a while.
Apperently your problem is a JavaScript syntax error and I found it here:
[angularjs form can not refer to input control when input name is array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205314/angularjs-form-can-not-refer-to-input-control-when-input-name-is-array)

You can use square-brackets. You have to reference your form element like this:

```
investForm['entity[entity_name]'].$error.pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use square brackets for the form name. Try replacing it with an underscore or something:

```
<form name="investForm">
  <label>Entity Name</label>
  <input name="entity_entity_name" rc-forms ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+$/" type="text" ng-model="invest.entity_name" ng-required="invest.is_entity" />
    <div ng-show="investForm.entity_entity_name.$dirty && investForm.entity_entity_name.$invalid">
      <span ng-show="investForm.entity_entity_name.$error.pattern">Error: Please use English characters only!</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i tried ng-show="investForm.entity['entity_name'].$error.pattern
and also ng-show="investForm.entity.entity_name.$error.pattern
neither worked

Comment: Don't use square brackets in form field names and you should be good.

Comment: this way the input's name is not an array.
when it's not an array there is no problem, but i cannot change the input's name. it's the syntax of the ng-show value that i'm passing that i have to change.

Comment: The input name is only a string identifier, why would it need to be an array?